# MySQL time-exceeded error

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on an AJAX testing platform. I am experiencing stupid errors in PHP programming. Here is my code. I get the error: **Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**.

```
<?php
$resultFromJson;

$databaseConnection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
if($databaseConnection)mysql_select_db("fastdata", $databaseConnection);
else echo mysql_error($databaseConnection);

if(isset($_GET['command'])){
    switch($_GET['command']){
        case "loadPeople":
        {
            $sqlCommandString = "SELECT * FROM  `people` LIMIT 0 , 30";

            $people = array();
            $index = 0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlCommandString))){
                $people[$index] = $row;
                $index++;   
            }

            echo json_encode( $people );
        }
        break;  
    }
}

if(!isset($_GET['command']))echo json_encode( "Error#001" );

?>
```

What can I do to solve this error? What actually causes the error?

**P.S.** I am currently testing my PHP script directly in the browser with main.php?command=loadPeople as URL.

Comment: @Ameer - recommending a longer timeout doesn't resolve the initial problem, just prolongs the infinite loop before the webserver times it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute the query, **then** loop through the results; don't try to re-execute the query in every iteration of the while

```
$resultset = mysql_query($sqlCommandString);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
```

As you're clearly just learning the basics, I'd suggest that you learn to use MySQLi or PDO rather than the deprecated MySQL library... being able to use prepared statements and bind variables doesn't affect this query, but knowing how to use them will become more important later

Comment: I am not new in PHP, but for some years, I reoriented myself to windows programming, so I haven't opened Dreamwaver for a while. I just try to remember some things as you see:)

Answer (score 1):

i haven't written any PHP code in a while so this is a wild guess but in this piece of code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlCommandString)))
```

you essentially have a neverending loop because `$row` will be assigned every time `mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlCommandString))` returns a result

you need to save `mysql_query($sqlCommandString)` into a variable and then `mysql_fetch_assoc` from that variable in a loop